# Props bugs with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I' learning to work with Redux, React & React Router.
I've face with such a problem:

When I redirect from "/" to the URL like "/details/{id}" using *Link* -  I see that a wrong action creator is called. Action creator from "/" component is called indead of component's one in "/details/{id}.

But if I refresh my page, everything will be fine. Correct action is called.

Routing with Link: `<Link to={`/details/${this.props.movie.id}`}>`

**Other bug:** if I press "Back" from this page to return to "/", I will get an error, that my props' data are undefined. 
Like, props are empty and the action creator for http-request is not called (?) from componentDidMount().

But if I refresh my page again, everything will be fine again.

What's wrong with routing?? Or redux?

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));


const Routes = () => {
    return <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/details/:id" component={MovieDetailsContainer} />
    </div>;
}
```

"/":

```
    class MoviesDiscover extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dicoverMovies();
    }

    render() {
      ...
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.movieItems,
        hasErrored: state.movieHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.movieIsLoading,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        dicoverMovies: (url) => dispatch(dicoverMovies(url))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MoviesDiscover);
```

"details/{id}":

```
class MovieDetailsContainer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var id = this.props.match.params.id;
        this.props.getMovie(id); // called from MoviesDiscover instead of this, after routing
    }

    render() {
        var id = this.props.match.params.id;
        ...
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        item: state.movieItems,
        hasErrored: state.movieHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.movieIsLoading,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getMovie: (url) => dispatch(getMovieDetails(url))
    };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MovieDetailsContainer);
```

Actions (the same for two reqests - actions for results, error and lodaing):

```
 ...
export function moviesDataSuccess(items) {
    return {
        type: MOVIES_RESULTS,
        isLoading: false,
        items: items
    };
}

       export function dicoverMovies() {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(moviesIsLoading(true));

            API.get(URL_MOVIE_DISCOVER)
              .then(response => {
                dispatch(moviesIsLoading(false));
                dispatch(moviesDataSuccess(response.data));
              })
              .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
                dispatch(moviesHasErrored(true))
              });
        };
    }

    export function getMovieDetails(id) {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(moviesIsLoading(true));

            API.get(URL_MOVIE_DETAILS(id))
              .then(response => {
                dispatch(moviesIsLoading(false));
                dispatch(moviesDataSuccess(response.data));
              })
              .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
                dispatch(moviesHasErrored(true))
              });
        };
    }
```

Reducers:

```
   export function movieHasErrored(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MOVIES_ERROR:
            return action.hasErrored;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function movieIsLoading(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MOVIES_LOADING:
            return action.isLoading;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function movieItems(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MOVIES_RESULTS:
            return action.items;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    movieHasErrored, 
    movieIsLoading, 
    movieItems
});
```

I will be happy to all the recommendations. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

React router matches the closes URL first, I think the issue is the order of your component.
I suggest you order them like this and it should get resolved:

```
const Routes = () => {
    return <div>
        <Route path="/details/:id" component={MovieDetailsContainer} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
    </div>;
}
```

Also React Router has a component for switching between URLs that you can take advantage if your URLs are ambiguous:

```
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
 ...
 <Switch>
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/company" component={Company} />
        <Route path="/:user" component={User} />
 </Switch>
```

**PS:** Sorry I just wanted to comment instead of posting this answer if this is not the answer you're looking for, I just don't yet have reputation to comment directly :|

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in other place.

The problem was, I was using the same action-type for list results and details reasult.

When I was opening a page for details results, I've got props from previous page with list results ('cause they use the same action-type). Before my Details Component would fetch new data.

And my code was failing in render with wrong data.